# Mobile Web Form - Can radio buttons be custom styled for Android and iPhone with CSS & HTML?

Tags: css, mobile, webforms, cross-browser, cross-platform

My question is fairly straight-forward, however, side note: I also would like to make sure that any customizations degrade easily for other phones.

*Can radio buttons be custom styled for Android and iPhone with CSS & HTML?*

Thanks,
s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even bother without some Javascript, it's probably in your best interest to check if the browser is webkit and then customize from there, you can also try looking at jQueryMobile, they are doing some very cool things with all sorts of form controls: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html